# Android App Icon intent category seems inconsistent

Tags: android, android-intent

Clicking my app icon will sometimes take me to the launcher activity, but other times it will resume the activity where it left off (emulates the behavior of clicking the application in recents).

I've read (can't find concrete docs about this, other than a one off post from 3 years ago by Diane Hackborn) that after about half an hour, the OS will make sure that when you click the app icon, it will relaunch the app, but sometimes it seems to do this directly after I exit the application (with the home button, not the back button as that will call finish on the activity).

1. Why is this?
2. Is there any way to force the launcher activity in the Android OS without killing the app first then restarting it? I need to test how my app handles the launcher activity after the application may already be running.

Answer (score 1):

1. Android will free up memory whenever it feels necessary. For that, it will kill inactive apps. If your app goes to background, at some point Android will probably kill it. Matter of time.
2. You can kill your app, or you can make it kill itself when it goes to background. No more options.

in order to make your app kill itself, you should override the `onPause()` method (which is always called when the app goes to background) and add in it a call to `onDestroy()`.